# Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'baselineOffset'

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, nsattributedstringkey

I am using **NSAttributedStringKey** in **Swift 4**. While compiling with **Swift 3** I am getting this error. What is the equivalent of **baselineOffset** property in **Swift 3**.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples.

```
let attributes = [NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : 0.0] as [String : Any]
```